# How to import candlestick_ohlc and candlestick2_ohlc in Matplolib.finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some-what old code where I was using a method called `candlestick2_ohlc` from `matplotlib` package. And the code goes something like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc

...
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=135)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4, facecolor='#131722')
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, ...)
...
```

And now it shows this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'
```

I'm using `python 3.7.6` and `matplotlib 3.1.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time, I've found out that `matplotlib.finance` was deprecated since version `2.0` according to the official documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html). And the `matplotlib` people have created a standalone package called [`mplfinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) that will replace a former package called `mpl_finance` by mid-2020.

So, starting from now. In order to use `candlestick2_ohlc`, you need to install `mplfinance` using `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
```

Then, you can import `candlestick2_ohlc` or `candlestick_ohlc` like so:

```
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
```